# Can I manage two cloudbees accounts from one sdk?

Tags: cloudbees

I have two cloudbees accounts - one personal and one for a company.
bees init lets me specify one set of credentials.
Is there a way I can manage both accounts with the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was easier than I thought - added my personal account as an admin account on the company account.